# Finding information on relative who joined Italian army in Somalia around 1935

Tags: military-records, world-war-2, 1930s, italy

My grand uncle joined Italian arms around 1935 in small town located in north east Somalia.  We do not know whether he died during World War 2 or whether he survived.

Can you guide me to any archive data that can help me to find out any information about him?

Comment: Hi Ahmed and welcome to the Genealogy & Family History SE. Be sure to take the [tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour).